# Works only in root folder

Tags: yii

My application written with YII framework works only if placed in root folder like: Localhost/
if I place it somewhere like: localhost/test, then it does not work(Links does not work, CSS is not attaching)
Where should I change it? thanks!

Comment: I googled a high likelihood of ['$homePath' configuration setting](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/116/how-to-set-up-directory-structures-for-multiple-yii-project-support) for you (protected/config/main.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should work around your basePath variable in protected/config/main.php.
In almost all cases it looks like

```
'basePath' => dirname(__FILE__).'/..'
```

But if this won't help you i think you should check your web-server config.